# Embedded Vimeo videos lost controls and logo after starting Pro trial

Tags: vimeo, react-player

I was able to embed Vimeo video just fine with the Basic account. However, I now started Pro trial and all controls disappeared. So, if I pass `playing={true}` to `<ReactPlayer>`, the video plays just fine. Otherwise, it looks as a screenshot of the first frame of the video. Even the Vimeo logo does not appear.

The controls are enabled in the video's settings (and appear in the player inside Vimeo):

[image]

[image]

What could be the reason for the controls not showing in the embedded videos?

Answer (score 0):

I had to explicitly pass `controls={true}` to `<ReactPlayer>`. It is unexpected and surprising that this is not the default...